# Style a parent div based on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a solution to apply CSS style to `div2`, only when `div1` is visible. How can I do that?

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div> 

<style>
    /* when div1 is NOT present */
    .div2 {
        margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
    }

    /* when div1 IS present */
    .div2 {
        margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Javascript required; you can use the CSS 'sibling' selector to achieve this:

```
.div2 {
    margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
}

.div1 + .div2 {
    margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
}
```

Of course this only applies when the `.div1` element is not present in the DOM (as per the comment in your code sample). If you want to do this when `div1` is present but hidden then you would need to use JS.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: What a shame we can't use a minus to find siblings before instead of only after!

Comment: @Le-roy That sounds like a nice idea, but it wouldn't make much sense. If you find yourself in a need to know what is the state of previous elements, you're approaching the problem from the wrong angel. Look at my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing this kind of behaviour is setting a base class on their top level parent (could be even `<body>`, and from there you can set any behaviour you want, purely by CSS.

```css
.menu_open .div1 {
  display: block;
}

.menu_open .div2 {
  display: none;
}

.div1 {
  display: none;
}

.div2 {
  display: block;  
}
```

```html
<body class="menu_open">
    <div class="div1">Div1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div2</div>
</body>
```

Now you can toggle between the states of the `<body>` classes using JS, and you can set complicated behaviours to any other elements, independent to other siblings.

Answer (score -1):

A little jQuery always helps,Use the :visible selector of jquery

```
if($('.div1').is(':visible')) 
{    
     $('.div2').css('margin','0 auto 100px auto'); 
}
else
{
     $('.div2').css('margin','100px auto 100px auto');
}
```